# How can query be optimized using CASE in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a query with Union statements, just to check like case but i want to implement CASE in Where, but i am beginner to SQL and dont know how can i do that.

My Query is like

```
SELECT TOP 1 EndDate
           FROM   (
                      SELECT 1 AS seq,

                             EndDate,

                      FROM   pipeline_rest_envr_info e
                      WHERE  e.tckt_id = imt.tckt_id
                             AND stat = 'INPR'
                      UNION
                      SELECT TOP 1 2 AS seq,

                             EndDate,

                      FROM   pipeline_rest_envr_info e
                      WHERE  e.tckt_id = imt.tckt_id
                             AND stat = 'CMPL'
                      ORDER BY
                             enddate DESC
                      UNION
                      SELECT TOP 1 3 AS seq,

                             EndDate,

                      FROM   pipeline_rest_envr_info e
                      WHERE  e.tckt_id = imt.tckt_id
                             AND stat = 'PLND'
                      ORDER BY
                             strt_dt
                      UNION 
                      SELECT 4 AS seq,

                             NULL,

                      FROM   pipeline_rest_envr_info e
                      WHERE  e.tckt_id = imt.tckt_id
                  ) aa
           ORDER BY
                  aa.seq
```

Comment: where "imt" alias comes from? i do think there is something missing in your code..

Comment: I also think the inner union is either missing other information or is not constructed correctly. Why are some not ordered, some are ordered by a date column ascending, and some are ordered by a date column descending? Maybe instead of telling us what you're trying to fix about this questionable query, you could show us your table structure, sample data, and desired results. This does not seem like the right approach to find a single row in one table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT TOP 1 EndDate 
           FROM   (
           select (case when stat = 'INPR' then 1
                       when stat = 'CMPL' then 2
                       when stat = 'PLND' then 3
                       else 4 end
                     ) as seq,EndDate
            from pipeline_rest_envr_info e 
           left outer join table2name imt on e.tckt_id = imt.tckt_id   
                  ) aa
           ORDER BY
                  aa.seq

Comment: Why are you posting two separate answers? Should we only believe one of them? Also please use the `{ }` button to highlight code samples.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TOP 1 aa.* 
           FROM   ( 
           select (case when condition1 then result1 
                        when condition2 then result2 
                        ... 
                        else 
                        default_result 
                        end  ) as result,... from tablename  
                  ) aa 
           ORDER BY 
                  aa.seq

Answer (score 0):

Avoid implementation of CASE in WHERE. Instead apply it in SELECT. Further you have not mentioned the table representing the alias IMT

SELECT TOP 1 EndDate
FROM (
select
(
case when stat = 'INPR' then 1
     when stat = 'CMPL' then 2
     when stat = 'PLND' then 3
     else 4 end
) as seq,EndDate
from pipeline_rest_envr_info e
inner join whateverthetablenameis imt on e.tckt_id = imt.tckt_id
) aa
ORDER BY aa.seq

Comment: `Never implement CASE in WHERE` ***why?*** Also, please use the `{ }` button to highlight code samples.

Comment: I dint knew about {} as I am new here. Anyways, thanks. And I meant avoid using of case in where as it is comparatively difficult to handle it in where clause and far simpler in select clause